# is it possible to use OAUTH2 with no userInfoUri?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to build social login to my application, only for the purpose of identifying users and keeping their "preferences" separate.  I was able to find this great guide:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

And set up a web application that allowed the user to log in with Google and Facebook.  I use the Client ID and the "Name" to uniquely identify users.  Name being the unique id code given by the oAuth provider, not something like "John Smith".  But I've run into a brick wall trying to add many other social logins, like Yahoo or Twitch.  I can't seem to find a "userInfoUri" for these oAuth providers, and I while I can get the page to approve my site to appear, it throws errors after returning to my site about being unable to extract user details.  Is there any easier way to do this?  I'm not trying to access their email address, or real name.  I just want a unique identifier.

Comment: The userinfo_endpoint is a concept within OpenID Connect not within OAuth 2.0.

Comment: From what I can gather from the example I listed, the application creates a filter chain.  ResourceServerTokenServices, (UserInfoTokenServices) implementation is responsible for populating the Principal with details (which here calls a web service).  I assume this might be useful if you are trying to get information like a user picture, or email address - but I simply want to get a unique user id.  I can't seen to find\get an example working that gets just this information.  The closest I have found is some information on decoding the JWT Token and extracting the information.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.  Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: not yet, was able to get some information from Jwt decodedToken = JwtHelper.decode((String) existingToken.getAdditionalInformation().get("id_token"));  Then you have to fill up the principal yourself.